Why isn't terraform minifying this policy JSON?
I am trying to use the AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup policy in an IAM role with:
data "aws_iam_policy" "aws_backup_service_policy" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "backup_service_aws_backup_role_policy" {
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy.aws_backup_service_policy.policy
  role   = aws_iam_role.backup_service_role.name
}

Which results in:

Error: putting IAM role policy terraform-20240401140929162200000001: LimitExceeded: Maximum policy size of 10240 bytes exceeded for role foundry-terraform-backup-service-role-dev


This makes sense, as the json for the role is actually over the maximum policy size. However, I've tried minifying the JSON with:

```hcl
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "backup_service_aws_backup_role_policy" {
  policy = jsonencode(jsondecode(data.aws_iam_policy.aws_backup_service_policy.policy))
  role   = aws_iam_role.backup_service_role.name
}

as described here:

"As of Terraform 0.12, you can produce minified JSON using a round-trip through jsondecode and jsonencode, because jsonencode always produces minimal JSON"

If I create an output, I can verify that the value has indeed been minified:
output "policy_json" {
  value = jsonencode(jsondecode(data.aws_iam_policy.aws_backup_service_policy.policy))
  description = "the policy json"

but when I try to apply the configuration, I end up with the same error. Why is the policy not being minified on apply?

Minification won't help, because IAM already ignores interstitial whitespace in policies; See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_iam-quotas.html#reference_iam-quotas-entity-length

The AWS provider also automatically minifies whatever you pass to the policy argument of aws_iam_role_policy before passing it to the remote API, and so the round-trip through jsondecode and jsonencode is redundant here.

What I would try doing in this case is just provide the ARN of the AWS managed policy and attach it using the aws_iam_role_policy_attachment resource:
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "backup_service_aws_backup_role_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSBackupServiceRolePolicyForBackup"
  role       = aws_iam_role.backup_service_role.name
}


This is a perfect solution, thank you!
